# I can't set my custom ICO icons on toolbar buttons in Win32 application

Tags: c++, winapi, icons, toolbar

I apologize for my poor English. I write a C ++ application in the Win32 API in Visual Studio 2017 Community on Windows 10. The application has a toolbar with buttons. I want to assign my custom functionality to each button. Therefore, each button must have its custom specific icon. (I added the icons to the application’s ResourceFiles folder.) ***The problem is that I can’t install my custom ICO icons on the buttons in the toolbar.*** When I run my application, the buttons are empty without icons. I re-read a lot of information on this topic on SO and on other sites. Still, I can’t install my icons on the buttons. I would be very grateful if anyone would help. Thank you in advance. Below is my code, with which I try to put my icons on the toolbar buttons:

```
#define IDM_INPUT 0
#define IDM_OUTPUT 1
#define IDM_TRIANGULATE 2
#define IDM_STOP 3  

HWND CreateSimpleToolbar(HWND hWndParent)
{
    // Declare and initialize the constants used in the function:
    // - picture list id for buttons,
    const int ImageListID = 0;
    // - number of buttons,
    const int numButtons = 4;
    // - the size of each image for the button.
    const int bitmapSize = 16;

    const DWORD buttonStyles = BTNS_AUTOSIZE;

    // Create the toolbar.
    HWND hWndToolbar = CreateWindowEx(0, TOOLBARCLASSNAME, NULL,
        WS_CHILD | TBSTYLE_WRAPABLE, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        hWndParent, NULL, hInst, NULL);

    if (hWndToolbar == NULL)
        return NULL;

    // Create a list of pictures for buttons.
    g_hImageList = ImageList_Create(bitmapSize, bitmapSize,
        ILC_COLOR16 | ILC_MASK, // Provide a transparent background.
        numButtons, 0);

    ImageList_AddIcon(g_hImageList, LoadIcon(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1)));
    ImageList_AddIcon(g_hImageList, LoadIcon(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON2)));
    ImageList_AddIcon(g_hImageList, LoadIcon(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON3)));
    ImageList_AddIcon(g_hImageList, LoadIcon(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON4)));

    // Set a list of pictures for buttons.
    SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_SETIMAGELIST,
        (WPARAM)ImageListID,
        (LPARAM)g_hImageList);

    // Upload pictures for buttons.
    SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_LOADIMAGES,
        (WPARAM)IDB_STD_SMALL_COLOR,
        (LPARAM)HINST_COMMCTRL);

    // Initialize information about buttons.
    TBBUTTON tbButtons[numButtons] =
    {
        { MAKELONG(IDI_ICON1,  ImageListID), IDM_INPUT,  TBSTATE_ENABLED, buttonStyles, {0}, 0, 0 },
        { MAKELONG(IDI_ICON2, ImageListID), IDM_OUTPUT, TBSTATE_ENABLED, buttonStyles, {0}, 0, 0},
        { MAKELONG(IDI_ICON3, ImageListID), IDM_TRIANGULATE, TBSTATE_ENABLED, buttonStyles, {0}, 0, 0},
        { MAKELONG(IDI_ICON4, ImageListID), IDM_STOP, TBSTATE_ENABLED, buttonStyles, {0}, 0, 0}
    };

    // Add buttons.
    SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_BUTTONSTRUCTSIZE, (WPARAM)sizeof(TBBUTTON), 0);
    SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_ADDBUTTONS, (WPARAM)numButtons, (LPARAM)&tbButtons);

    // Resize the toolbar and then show it.
    SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_AUTOSIZE, 0, 0);
    ShowWindow(hWndToolbar, TRUE);

    return hWndToolbar;
}
```

IDI_ICON1, IDI_ICON2, IDI_ICON3 and IDI_ICON4 are the identifiers of the four ICO icon files resulting from the addition of these icons to the application resources.
If I check the result of the LoadIcon function in the debugger, I will see the message "Unable to read memories", although the returned HICON value itself is not zero.
Please tell me what needs to be fixed in the above code?

Comment: The `IDI_ICONx` identifiers are the resource IDs of the icons but are probably not going to be the same values as the indexes of the images you add to the image list. E.g. if `IDI_ICON1` is the first image added to the image list, its index will be `0` and this is what you must use in the `TBBUTTON` structure. Also, you can remove the `TB_LOADIMAGES` call as it's not needed unless you actually want to use the system-supplied images.

Comment: **Jonathan**, thank you for good comment that is really help me. All works, the icons are displayed!